# adding url at the end of reference

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using sharelatex for my documentation work. I am doing my reference section with biblatex. While adding my reference all the url that I have used are cited at the beginning. I would like to have these URL towards the end of my reference section.

For eg

1. Article 1,
2. Article 2,
   3.URL
   4.URL

below is the code I am using.

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}    
@article{dt3,
    author        = {Leo.},
    title         = {forests.},
    journaltitle  = {45.1},
    year          = {2003},
   %volume        = {911},
    %number        = {14},
    pages         = {5-32},
    %doi           = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004}
}
@online{stack,
author        = {},
    title         = {},
    year          = {},
    url           = {http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111968/random-forest-how-to-handle-overfitting},
}
```

I am new to this platform and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Does https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber#Separate_Bibliographies_by_Entry_Type help?

Comment: @Johannes_B I tried it , but i am unsuccessful. I wanted to sort the reference with papers first and then these URLs. But according to my style, it takes it by the chapters.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a split bibliography: One `\printbibliography` for non-`@online` sources and one for `@online`. A split bibliography makes it clearer why the numbering is different from the usual scheme.

Don't forget the `defernumbers=true` option if you use a numeric style.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric-comp, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
}
@online{elk,
  author  = {Anne Elk},
  title   = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date    = {1972},
  url     = {http://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  urldate = {2018-09-22},
}
@article{hacker,
  author  = {James Hacker},
  title   = {On Government},
  journal = {Government and Governing},
  volume  = {123},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {109-123},
  date    = {1981},
}
@online{weisel,
  author  = {Frank Weisel},
  title   = {It Takes Two to Quango},
  date    = {1980},
  url     = {http://example.com/~weisel/quango.pdf},
  urldate = {2018-09-22},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby,elk,hacker,weisel}
\printbibliography[nottype=online]
\printbibliography[type=online, title={Online Sources}]
\end{document}
```

[image: References//1 Humphrey Appleby. On the Importance of the Civil Service. 1980.//2 James Hacker. ‘On Government’. In: Government and Governing 123.4 (1981), pp. 109–123.//Online Sources//3 Anne Elk. A Theory on Brontosauruses. 1972. url: http://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf (visited on 22/09/2018).//4 Frank Weisel. It Takes Two to Quango. 1980. url: http://example.com/~weisel/quango.pdf (visited on 22/09/2018).]